# I send a PUT request, but receive GET

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter

I have an API made with CodeIgniter Rest Extension... was working perfectly but today it start to fail.

I came to this test:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once(APPPATH . "/libraries/REST_Controller.php");
use Restserver\libraries\REST_Controller;

class Provincias extends REST_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function index_get($pId=0) {
    $response = array('status'=>'Get');
        $this->response($response);
    }

    public function index_put() {
    $response = array('status'=>'Put');
        $this->response($response);
    }

}
```

And using Postman, if I call a get, brings "GET" and if I call a put also brings a "GET"... what is wrong here? any ideas?

Comment: `header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");`

Comment: " if I call a put also brings a "GET"". What do you mean by "brings" or "receives" a GET? The server can only _respond_ to your initial request. It cannot send you back a different request. If you send a PUT, it stays as a PUT the whole time. The response cannot be using a different HTTP method. Are you referring to the header information you're seeing in the response, which is likely to be produced by the line of code that line88 has highlighted in the comment above? Please clarify and try to be specific and detailed about what is happening

Comment: P.S. "it start to fail" ...fail how exactly? Again, what precise result are you seeing? If there's an error or other symptom of failure then please describe it to us. Don't forget we cannot read your screen, your disk...or your mind. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson I say it at the end of the post... If I call a get, brings a GET, and if I call a put, also brings a GET... It always bring GET!

Comment: And I already said that your comment doesn't really make sense, and then I explained why. That is why I then asked you to clarify your meaning, not just repeat your original statement. I didn't understand it before, so unsurprisingly I can't understand it the 2nd time. Can you read my comment again please? And then give a full, detailed explanation of what you see. "brings a GET" is neither a technical term from which we can understand you, nor a screenshot, nor a paste of your output. It doesn't actually mean anything, and the way you've worded it appears to contradict how HTTP actually works

Comment: I think for your words that you are mad, and don't understand why... I'll explain again... when I call a GET REQUEST of a method, it execute the GET METHOD... the problem was, that when I called a PUT REQUEST, instead of executing the PUT METHOD, was executing the GET METHOD and brings the response "status"=>"get" (as in the example) instead of "status"=>"put"... I think I solved but thanks anyway...

Comment: the response "status"=>"get" is not necessarily indicative of the HTTP method used. It's just the data returned by a PHP function. The server **cannot** change the HTTP method. It can, internally, change which function it runs to deal with your request, and what data it gives you in the body of the response. But that's not the same thing as what you were describing, as if the actual HTTP method was changed. It wasn't clear what you were really seeing. As to why it does that when you don't use HTTPS, it's not really obvious from the code. Maybe it's a rule elsewhere in codeigniter or apache.

Comment: P.S. and yes I was a little disappointed that you just repeated your original statement without clarifying, and that you appeared to be implying that I hadn't read your post. Sorry if I came across as harsh. But now I'm happier that you replied in more detail :-)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, but I'm not sure how... I was calling the API with http:// instead of https:// so... I presume that when you call 'http' it only invoke the GET method... even if you send a PUT request... It only send back a PUT method when I called it with https...

I'm not sure if this is right, but... maybe help someone...